# MySQL google app engine at local machine - error

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I am programming an local machine with Google App Engine and connect MySql to my project and when I am trying to connect to mysql I have an error. Have any idea? 
Googling gave only one similar thing: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45029/mysql-exception-after-upgrading-from-java-6-to-java-7

```
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private"
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.initializeProperties(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:2819)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializeDriverProperties(ConnectionImpl.java:3490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at ru.onekilometre.SQLConnectionProvider.getInstance(SQLConnectionProvider.java:18)
at ru.onekilometre.OnekilometreServlet.doGet(OnekilometreServlet.java:19)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:480)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Connection code is:

```
package ru.onekilometre;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection;


public class SQLConnectionProvider {
public static Connection connection;
public static Connection getInstance() throws Exception {

      if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
        return connection;
      }
     // if (true) {
        //MySQL
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onekilometre";
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "raiym", "password");
    /*  } else {
        // Google Cloud SQL
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
        String instanceName = "somename";
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://" + instanceName + "/NAME_DB");
      }*/
      return connection;
    }
```

}

Comment: What Java version/GAE SDK version are you using?

Comment: 1.7.0? Not 1.7.0_25 or similar?

Comment: oh, sorry, you are right: build 1.7.0_25-b15

Comment: It would seem then that the question you linked applies, apparently there are problems with 1.7.0_25 that are fixed by downgrading to 1.7.0_21.

Comment: Thank you Jaochim! I reinstalled jre with 1.7.0_21 and it works go me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your connection string from:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onekilometre"
```

to
    "jdbc:google:rdbms://instance_name/database"

where you replace `instance_name` with with your Google Cloud SQL instance name and `database` with your database name. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide#connect_and_post. For instance, in my app I have:

```
"jdbc:google:rdbms://namibiaonthenet:namibiaonthenet/barcodeapp"
```

App Engine **automatically** replaces this string to connect to your local MySQL instance if you run on the local server according to the settings you set when going to Project Properties | Google | App Engine | Google Could SQL and then clicking on `Configure`. Remember to select the `Use MySQL instance` radio button.

No need to change your connection string each time! If you run locally, your local instance will be used. If you run from the Google servers, the cloud instance will be used.

Answer (score 6):

Like Jaochim sad problem was with jre1.7.0_25
I reinstalled to jre1.7.0_21 and it works. 
Thanks.

Comment: raiym i am stuck with this solution, i have tried the solution which is considered as answer, but it is not working, can you please tell me which approach worked for you

Comment: hello. I give up with mysql and did like Floris sad. I payed cloud sql instance and turn it on on Eclipse Project -> Properties -> App Engine and Enable Google Cloud SQL. But another way (for free) it's using Datastore instead Google cloud sql. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Comment: This also worked for me.  I was on jdk1.7.0_25.  Upgrading to jdk1.7.0_51 fixed things for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with jre1.7.0_25, and resolved it by upgrading to jre1.7.0_45.